# Guruvayoor Mahatmyam in Narada Purana?

Tags: puranas, temple, narada, guruvayoor, edition

I have heard that there is a chapter called     'Guruvayoor Mahatmyam' in Narada Purana. But I couldn't find it in the editions I am reading. Does Anyone has a link to this specific chapter ?